# coinFlip heads streak output

Tags: java

I'm supposed to flip a coin 100 times, and find out the longest streak of heads, then output it, but so far, it's only giving me how many heads there are in total. I've tried a bunch of things but can't find a solution.

```
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public static final int FLIPS = 100;

    public void run()
    {
        int h = 0;
        int t = 0;
        boolean wasHeads = false;
        boolean isHeads = false;
        int streak = 0;
        int ih = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++) {
            int coinFlip = Randomizer.nextInt(1, 2);

            if (coinFlip == 2) {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                h++;
                ih++;
                isHeads = true;

                if (ih > 1) {
                    wasHeads = true;
                }
                if ((isHeads = true) && (wasHeads = true)) {   
                    streak++;
                } else {
                    streak = 0;
                }
            } else if (coinFlip == 1) {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                t++;  
                isHeads = false;
                ih = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(streak);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the Randomizer actually gives a tails from time to time?

Comment: `if ((isHeads = true) && (wasHeads = true))` will always be `true`.  You're not doing a _comparison_ here (e.g. `if (isHeads && wasHeads)`), you're doing an _assignment_ (and the return of an assignment is the value being assigned; in this case `true`).  Additionally you never set `wasHeads` to `false` again.  Which means once it gets set to `true`, it will stay `true` from then on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to substantially simplify your code.

```
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public static final int FLIPS = 100;

    public void run()
    {
        int wasHeads = 0;
        int streak = 0;
        int bestStreak = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++) {
            int coinFlip = Randomizer.nextInt(1, 2);

            if (coinFlip == 2) {
                streak++;
                wasHeads = 1;
            } else if (coinFlip == 1) {
                wasHeads = 0;
                if (steak > bestStreak) {
                    bestStreak = streak;
                }
                streak = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(streak);
    }
}
```

Reset streak when it ends (coinFlip is 1), but first check if it's better than your best streak before then, updating the bestStreak if so accordingly.  Otherwise, just iterate streak and keep wasHeads at 1 for each head.  Note there's not need for a boolean here; a 1 or 0 integer is literally and logically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, fix your line here so it's easier to read: `}} else if (coinFlip == 1) {`
(You need a newline between those two close braces)

I would consider setting up some more clear variable names. For example: `totalHeads`, `totalTails`. I'm not quite getting what your `ih` variable is SUPPOSED to be, but the variable names I would use for solving this problem are `thisStreak` and `bestStreak`. is/washeads should be unnecessary. I think that should be enough of a push to get you to a solution.

Comment: Delta using canonical Java naming conventions, e.g., `totalHeads`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code a bit, `wasHeads` and `isHeads` are not really needed. Also, more descriptive variable names makes your code easier to understand. So, something like this:

```
public void run() {
    int highestNumberOfConsecutiveHeads = 0;
    int currentNumberOfConsecutiveHeads = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (Randomizer.nextInt(1, 2) == 2) {
            currentNumberOfConsecutiveHeads++;
            if (currentNumberOfConsecutiveHeads > largestNumberOfConsecutiveHeads) {
                highestNumberOfConsecutiveHeads = currentNumberOfConsecutiveHeads;
            }
        } else {
            currentNumberOfConsecutiveHeads = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Longest streak: " + highestnumberOfConsecutiveHeads);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, fixed my code :)

```
public class LongestStreak extends ConsoleProgram
```

{
    public static final int FLIPS = 100;

```
public void run()
{
    int h = 0;
    int t = 0;
    boolean wasHeads = false;
    boolean isHeads = false;
    int longest = 0;
    int streak = 0;
    int ih = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < FLIPS; i++) {

        int coinFlip = Randomizer.nextInt(1, 2);

        if (coinFlip == 2) { //heads

            System.out.println("Heads");

            if (wasHeads = true) {
                streak++;
            } else {
                streak = 0;
            }

            wasHeads = true;
        } else if(coinFlip == 1) { //tails

            System.out.println("Tails");

            t++;

            isHeads = false;
            if (streak > longest){
                longest = streak;
            }

            streak = 0;

            ih = 0;

        }

    }

    System.out.println("Longest streak of heads: " + longest);
}
```

}